# Why did Jesus weep for Jerusalem?

Tags: life-of-jesus

My question is why Jesus wept for Jerusalem?

Is the reason that Jesus had a previous experience of rising from death? If the previous life and death become operational together with the present life, countless persons will die and put to disadvantages if he dies?

Because besides his disciples there were innumerable followers with or without the approval of the state authority? Was Jesus worried about that possibility?

```
      It was written in the scriptures that Jesus will die and bring glory to God. Jesus was successful in his suicidal attempt. As a result, countless persons suffered and died. It was a conspiracy, which Jesus knew partly beforehand and prepared with sadism in his mind. Teachers of the law and Pharisees were not aware who was Jesus among them until Judas Iscariot betrayed him saying "I am ready to betray Jesus".Jesus was caught. His disciples were ready to see him die as early as possible perhaps was the reason that he wept for JERUSALEM.
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on "Jesus had a previous experience of rising from death"? What "previous life and death" are you referring to? According to the scriptures, "Christ died once for all time". (1 Peter 3:18)

Comment: @agarza Christ died for all time completing his duty. Why the fighting continued for seventy-five years? user-37920

Comment: Please [edit] this to quote the passage you are referring to.

Comment: @curiousdannil-What Jesus made clear when he said "you will be witnesses unto me both in JERUSALEM ,in Judea, Samaria and in uppermost parts of the earth? There were countless risen people around them. user-37920

Comment: @curiousdannil-Jesus uttered these sentences after he reappeared after death.user-37920

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jesus knew the hearts of those that were there, that they rejected not only the prophets, but they rejected Him the Messiah.
Let's take a look at the Scripture in question Luke 19:41-44
"And when he drew near and saw the city, he wept over it, saying, “Would that you, even you, had known on this day the things that make for peace! But now they are hidden from your eyes. For the days will come upon you, when your enemies will set up a barricade around you and surround you and hem you in on every side and tear you down to the ground, you and your children within you. And they will not leave one stone upon another in you, because you did not know the time of your visitation.”

We see here that since they refused Jesus, that they would reap destruction, and this is exactly what happened in AD 70 by Titus who later became Emperor of Rome. Jesus was foretelling the Roman siege of the city, in which the city was sieged and was destroyed.